# How to loop over 2 things in asyncio using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am very new to asyncio and REST APIs in general. I had a rudimentary code working using requests but it was very slow (20-30 minutes), and it seems like `asyncio` and `aiohttp` are the tools I need to use to improve this situation.

What my code does is send a get request to an endpoint which returns a list of `jobid`s and a `next_url` to continue searching the endpoint for more `jobid`s. I have a quick filter to see if I want to search this job or not, and if I do, I use its `jobid` to get a list of `fileid`s. I then have a test to see if I want those files, and if I do I download them.

When doing this synchronously I do something like this:

```
import json
import os
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import Generator

import requests

Job = namedtuple("Job", "jobid name owner")
File = namedtuple("File", "fileid name path")

OWNER_FILTER = 'Drphoton'
FILENAME_FILTER = ['filename_a.txt', '.png']

BATCH_SIZE = 100
JOBS_ENDPOINT = 'https://website.com/jobs/'
API_KEY = os.environ.get('MYAPIKEY')


def main():
    for job in get_all_jobs(JOBS_ENDPOINT):
        if not keep_job(job):
            continue
        for file in get_all_files(job):
            if keep_file(file):
                download(file)


def get_all_jobs(job_url: str) -> Generator[Job, None, None]:
    """Gets basic info about all jobs.
    Lazily returns a Job object.
    """
    while job_url is not None:
        result = requests.get(job_url,
                              params={"page_size": BATCH_SIZE},
                              headers={"Authorization": f"Token {API_KEY}"})
        if not (result.status_code == 200 and result.content):
            continue
        json_data = json.loads(result.content)
        results = json_data['results']
        for job_result in results:
            yield Job(jobid=job_result['id'],
                      status=job_result['status'],
                      owner=job_result['owner'],
                      name=job_result['name'])
        job_url = json_data['next']


def get_all_files(job: str, job_url: str) -> Generator[File, None, None]:
    """Gets basic info about all files within a job.
    Lazily returns a File object.
    """
    file_url = f"{job_url}{job.jobid}/files/"
    while file_url is not None:
        result = requests.get(job_url,
                              params={"page_size": BATCH_SIZE},
                              headers={"Authorization": f"Token {API_KEY}"})
        if not (result.status_code == 200 and result.content):
            continue
        json_data = json.loads(result.content)
        results = json_data['results']
        for file_result in results:
            yield Job(jobid=job_result['id'],
                      owner=job_result['owner'],
                      name=job_result['name'])
        file_url = json_data['next']

def keep_job(job: Job) -> bool:
    """Tests if we should keep the job based on certain filters, and returns a boolean"""
    if OWNER_FILTER not in job.owner:
        return False
    return True


def keep_file(file: File) -> bool:
    """Tests if we should keep the job based on certain filters, and returns a boolean"""
    if any(NAME in file.name for NAME in FILENAME_FILTER):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This works, but is crazy slow for a relatively small number of jobs and files. I tried to adapt this to async code using the tools mentioned above, but it doesn't seem to actually run asynchronously. I'm a bit at a loss on how to improve it. I feel like what's tripping me up is that part of the json payload is a link to the "next page", so I can't get ALL of the job names and search them all at once --- I need to somehow asynchronously look up the next page of jobs while the files-for-loop is looking up file names, but I can't figure out how to do that cleanly. In fact, it seems I'm not even looking up the filenames for multiple jobs simultaneously either!

Here is my best attempt at an async version of the code above. It runs but isn't much faster. I'm mainly highlighting the differences to above to show you how I've implemented it:

```
import aiohttp

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async for job in get_all_jobs(job_url=JOBS_ENDPOINT, session=session):
            if keep_job(job):
                continue
            async for file in get_all_files(job, job_url=JOBS_ENDPOINT, session=session):
                if keep_file(file):
                    download(file)

async def get_all_jobs(job_url: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession) -> Generator[list[Job], None, None]:
    while job_url is not None:
        async with session.get(job_url,
                               params={"page_size": BATCH_SIZE},
                               headers={"Authorization": f"Token {API_KEY}"}) as resp:
            if not (resp.status == 200 and resp.content):
                continue
            json_data = await resp.json()
            for job in json_data['results']:
                yield Job(jobid=job['id'],
                          owner=job['owner'],
                          name=job['name'])
            job_url = json_data['next']
```

and something similar for `get_all_files()`. If I had to pinpoint my misunderstanding, it feels like `async for` doesn't really work asynchronously the way I would expect. My understanding is that anything called using `await` or `async for` is added to the event loop, and python is smart enough to keep track of all of these items and jump to the first that completes, carrying on from there. Instead, it really seems like it loops through each job 1 at a time instead of simultaneously, going through each of their filenames 1 at a time. I expect my number of jobs and files to grow a lot in the coming year, so this problem is only going to get worse.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Things like `await` and `async for` are blocking. Your code can't advance to the next operation until whatever you are awaiting completes. The different between them and synchronous code is they introduce potential points that could lead to the event loop giving control to a different coroutine.

Comment: I thought `await` meant "while I wait for this line, I'm going to go look elsewhere." So I want it to "go look elsewhere" and re-run my loop!

Comment: It does. But "elsewhere" is not the next line of code; it's the next coroutine that's ready to run.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be creating few tasks which wait for data (`job_url`, `job_id`) from `asyncio.Queue` and perform the get_all_files, downloading, ... tasks independent of each other.

A pseudocode:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

queue = asyncio.Queue()


async def get_all_files_task():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            job_url, job_id = await queue.get()

            # get all files using aiohttp:
            # async with session.get(...)

            # perform keep file, download file...

            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

            # task is done, wait for another
            queue.task_done()
            print("Task done.")


async def main():

    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_all_files_task()) for _ in range(10)]

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        # here you will put into a queue job_url, job_id from get_all_jobs
        # async for job in get_all_jobs(job_url=JOBS_ENDPOINT, session=session):
        for i in range(20):
            queue.put_nowait((100, 200))

    # wait for queue to be empty
    await queue.join()

    # cancel the get_all_files_tasks
    for t in tasks:
        t.cancel()
        try:
            await t
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andrej. I'm coincidentally currently looking into creating tasks. I think those are more representative of what I had in mind in terms of just "adding to the event loop". It's still tricky for me though :/